# Frequent Down Voting

Tags: discussion

It seems the recently there has been an increase in down voting on answers. While I'm fine with criticism, I think just down voting without providing a comment on the reasoning is unhelpful. How does the down voter expect answers to improve if commentary isn't provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree.

I suspect it may just be because of a small audience. There are always going to be some irrational downvotes, whether accidentally (for example, because they missed the upvote button) or arbitrarily (for example, because you used insufficient semi-colons).

If the number of voters were larger, this wouldn't be an issue, since the genuine votes would far outweigh the irrational votes. But since we have a relatively small audience, this doesn't happen at present.

It seems the answer may be to have more people voting. Easy right?

Comment: I up voted this. :)

Comment: It only takes a handful of people to vote you to suspension.  I like to mass up vote.